# Call function after set timeout in Angular 12 TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I would like to use saveAsDraft function after set timeout process. But I get an error. What do I use for this? Callback, promise or ...

```
  export class EditBlogComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    //For draft save
    typingTimer:any;
    doneTypingInterval = 5000;
    ....

    saveAsDraft(blog:Blog) {
       console.log("Taslak kaydediliyor.", this.blog);
    }

    draftSecond(formValue: string) {
        clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
        this.typingTimer = setTimeout(saveAsDraft(this.blog), 
        this.doneTypingInterval);
    }
  }
```

Image;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to saveAsDraft should be inside a function.

The syntax is -

```
setTimeout(function(){ ... }, timeInMilliseconds);
```

So your call should be -

```
setTimeout(function(){
     saveAsDraft(this.blog);
}, timeInMilliseconds);
```

Additionally, just check if `this` is available inside the `function()`. It might not be. so you can do like -

```
var refToThis = this;
setTimeout(function(){
     refToThis.saveAsDraft(refToThis.blog);
}, timeInMilliseconds);
```

or use arrow functions

```
setTimeout(()=>{
     this.saveAsDraft(this.blog);
}, timeInMilliseconds);
```

You can not access `saveAsDraft` without `this` since that is a class member and can only be accessed using its object.

Comment: When I do like this, I got an error. "Cannot find name 'saveAsDraft'"

Comment: That's because the saveAsDraft() is a class function.

Comment: Thank you. The problem solved

Comment: Glad I could help :)